# Xcode IOS Deployment target Options

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode5

In Xcode there are 5 columns when entering the Deployment target like shown below.

[image]

Resolved / AppName / Config (Pods) / App Name/ IOS Default

What are all these columns/options for? Is there not just one IOS Deployment Target for the app.

I understand that because I use Cocoa pods there could be a separate deployment type for the pods, but why the two columns with app name and ios default etc?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the columns is a different place in the build system "hierarchy" where the value can come from. The rightmost is the default built into Xcode; moving from right to left, there's the overall project, the config file from Cocoapods, the per-target config, and the value that will actually take effect. If your project is part of a workspace, there's a level there, too.

You're right that for an app, there can be only one deployment target. But you can have more than one app in a project, and could have different deployment targets for each. Say you have the older version of your app that works all the way back to iOS 4.3, and a newer version that only works in iOS 7 and later. You could have them both be part of the same project in Xcode and use a different deployment target for each.

Comment: Thanks, so if I am creating an app that should be available for IOS6 devices what should they all be set to, all the same? What is the use of the default built into Xcode can it even be changed? 
Also if you have more than one app in the project, how is the resolved value worked out? You mention in your answer having an app that is 4.3 compat and another for ios7 so how would that be resolved as 4.3 -- surely then the ios7 app would not work?